# Form results sent to different emails

Tags: webforms

I am using a webform module to create a contact us form. The customer has asked for a dropdown list for the visitor to select whom they would like to contact (web administrator/general enquiry). Is there a way to change the TO email depending on the selection? Or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I did it in Drupal 7, without the use of any other add-on modules:

1. Add a select box to the form.
2. In the select box options field, add your info in this format:

   > email-1@address.com|Select Option 1
   >
   > email-2@address.com|Select Option 2
   >
   > email-3@address.com|Select Option 3
3. Save your form, then click on the "Emails" sub-tab of the "Webform" primary tab.
4. Choose "Component Value > The name of the field you created in step 1". Click "Add".
5. Adjust your settings as needed on the following page, and you're done! The webform will now send an email to the address associated with the choice selected in the select box.

Comment: Do the keys (the e-mail addresses) appear in the `SELECT`?

Comment: Thanks @hockey2112

I'd rather not display the email addresses though...

Comment: The email addresses are not displayed in the drop-down menu, but they are displayed in the code of that drop-down.

Comment: SOrry to bother you again @hockey2112

Re: The webform will not send an email to the address associated with the choice selected in the select box

DId you mean to say WILL or will not send an email?

Comment: Sorry, it should have said "will NOW send...". I just edited my answer to correct that issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you need 2 or more of the options to send to the same email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the [Webform rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module.
You can catch every webform submit and then apply actions on it depending on the submit values. This module helps exposing webform events to the rules module.

The Rules module is used to trigger actions on defined events, so for example when a webform is submitted you can create a condition (in Rules) that checks the dropdown value and then trigger an action that sends the mail accordingly. You can have as many rules as diferent recipients.

Comment: Thank you @drcelus

These rules, is that something I would set in my webform tab? I haven't been able to find it as yet, and the webforum rules readme file isn't making much sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, the module I mention is meant to be used with the Rules module. Rules is used to trigger actions on events, see my edit on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build your own module, hook_form_alter($your_forms_id) and add your own submit handler like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'YOUR_forms_id'){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_';
 }
}
```

PS:Your default (webform) submit handler is executed also ..

```
function  my_submit_($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('success!')
...
  drupal_mail($form_state['values']['your element'])...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at issues [[#800350]](http://drupal.org/node/800350) or [[#1026758]](http://drupal.org/node/1026758). In short: you can do so by adding the following (templated) code:

```
   /**
     * Implements hook_mail_alter
     * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/functio... *
     * @param array $message
     */
    function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
      if ($message['id'] == 'webform_submission') {
        if (isset($message['params']['node']) && isset($message['params']['submission'])) {
          $node = $message['params']['node'];
          $submission = $message['params']['submission'];
          // do your work, e.g. changing $message['from'], $message['to'], etc.
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

By using hook_mail_alter you will also catch resubmissions, that most other solutions don't.